# Javascript event of covered div element

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a question concerning the events of a covered div element.
Do I have any chance to get the mouse click event of the covered div element with class **progress-bar**. Unfortunately I can not reorder the elements in that way that div container with class **progress-bar** is a nested element.
It would be great if there would be any solution for my problem.

```
<div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 60%;" onClick="alert('I need this event')">
    <span class="sr-only">60% Complete</span>
</div>
```

If I remove the div container with **personalHourFieldWrapper**:

```
<div class="personalHourFieldWrapper">
                    <span>&nbsp;</span>
                    <span>&nbsp;</span>
                    <span>&nbsp;</span>
                    <span>&nbsp;</span>
                    <span>&nbsp;</span>
                    <span>&nbsp;</span>
                    <span>&nbsp;</span>
                    <span>&nbsp;</span>
                    <span>&nbsp;</span>
                    <span>&nbsp;</span>
                    <span>&nbsp;</span>
                    <span>&nbsp;</span>
</div>
```

than it works like it should concerning the mouse click event but I need this twelve span containers absolutely.
So my aim is to get the mouse click event of div container with class **progress-bar** with this html structure.

[My JSFiddle testexample](https://jsfiddle.net/c4eyuoLt/1/)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually solve this with CSS.  Use `pointer-events:none;` on  `.personalHourFieldWrapper`.  The only downfall is that you'll lose any click events on that div.  There may also be some issues depending on browser.  [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/c4eyuoLt/2/) tested on Chrome and Edge.